# How to interprete the data from Pixel watch 2 EDA sensor?

Tags: android, wear-os

I recently tried the Pixel Watch 2 because of its various health-related sensors, including EDA (Electrodermal Activity) sensor. I was able to register and receive events from the sensor, but I'm not sure how to interprete the results. Do anyone know if Google released any documentation about the Pixel watch 2 EDA sensor?

Examples of the events I received from onSensorChange() - the first entry of the row is the timestamp of each event:

1697814182743,[370173.0, 501147.0, 624072.0, 741215.0, 552115.0, 368724.0, 206038.0, 54419.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182783,[213591.0, 371112.0, 510976.0, 640507.0, 460985.0, 283599.0, 124945.0, -22683.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182824,[140744.0, 302128.0, 444450.0, 576944.0, 398948.0, 223772.0, 67359.0, -77733.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182863,[86277.0, 249451.0, 394809.0, 529139.0, 352628.0, 179117.0, 24103.0, -119838.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182903,[47015.0, 211219.0, 357679.0, 493353.0, 317703.0, 145919.0, -8466.0, -152088.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182943,[15727.0, 180879.0, 327807.0, 463539.0, 289184.0, 116765.0, -36701.0, -179673.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814182983,[-11532.0, 153490.0, 301166.0, 438435.0, 264864.0, 93136.0, -59733.0, -201858.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814183022,[-34407.0, 132193.0, 280564.0, 418005.0, 245076.0, 73938.0, -77536.0, -219441.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814183062,[-50556.0, 116237.0, 264595.0, 402568.0, 230923.0, 60425.0, -91601.0, -232762.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

1697814183102,[-63904.0, 102562.0, 250841.0, 388963.0, 217071.0, 46788.0, -104393.0, -245124.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

I have tried searching through Android documentation and posts about pixel watch 2